# Maximum amount of sqlite databases in the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am creating an app where I am using multiple sqlite databases. I was wondering, is there a maximum of sqlite databases that I can have stored in the iPhone?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not currently a maximum amount of data or sqlite databases an app can store.

Comment: Didn't know I had to do that. I am assuming it is just using the checkmark? If so, done :)